# $\sqrt{ 1 - \zeta } = \sqrt{ \zeta }$?

Tags: probability-theory

In [this paper](http://www.research.scea.com/gdc2003/spherical-harmonic-lighting.pdf) (page 6) I'm reading, the author has a uniform random variable $\zeta$ which takes on values between 0 and 1.  He computes

$$
2 \arccos( \sqrt{ 1 - \zeta } )
$$

But isn't that the same as computing $2 \arccos( \sqrt{ \zeta } )$, since $\zeta$ is uniform on [0..1]?  Or is there a reason he may be doing that I'm missing?

Comment: They both have the same probability distribution.  But if in a particular case $\zeta$ happens to be equal to $0.25$, then $1-\zeta$ will not be equal to $0.25$, so you can't say they're equal, but only that their distributions are equal.

Comment: Let $\eta = 1- \zeta$. Then $\eta$ and $\zeta$ will have the same probability distribution. But the correlation between $\zeta$ and $\eta$ is different from the correlation between $\zeta$ and $\zeta$. So it really depends on what the author goes on to use the expression for.

Comment: @Willie Wong: +1 I thought of an expectation sign there (though, I see that there were no reasons for it). On the other hand my answer is still correct besides the phrase "You're right".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, if you consider $\eta = 1-\zeta$ then the distribution of $\eta$ is also uniform on $[0,1].$